Gradle dsl ruby gems build fails
I am using gradle 3.0 to build this but it fails no matter what I try.  I cannot upgrade to a newer version of gradle or any of the plugins and 3rd party jar files since this is part of a larger project with many other builds and to do that would take months to fix.  Does anyone know how to fix this ?  thanks in advance
plugins {
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '2.4.0'
    id 'com.github.jruby-gradle.base' version '1.7.0'
    id 'war'
}

jruby.defaultRepositories false

ext.asrPackage = "core"
ext.asrPackageType = "none"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    rubygems('https://rubygems.org')
}

dependencies {
    copyCompile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19.1'
    allTestCompile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.14'
}

dependencies {
    gems 'rubygems:asciidoctor-diagram:1.5.19'
}

asciidoctor {
    dependsOn jrubyPrepare
    sourceDir = file('doc')
    requires = ['asciidoctor-diagram']
    gemPath = jrubyPrepare.outputDir
    attributes \
        'build-gradle': file('build.gradle'),
    'source-highlighter' : 'coderay',
    'imagesdir': 'images',
    'toc': 'left',
    'icons': 'font',
    'setanchors': '',
    'idprefix': '',
    'idseparator': '-',
    'docinfo1': ''
}

build.dependsOn asciidoctor

